# Can we implement UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?

Tags: ios, swift, tvos

[The doc says "don't" :](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontrollercontexttransitioning)

> Do not adopt this protocol in your own classes, nor should you directly create objects that adopt this protocol. During a transition, the animator objects involved in that transition receive a fully configured context object from UIKit.

But if we take a look at `UIViewControllerContextTransitioning` declaration in the UIKit framework :

```
// 
// ...
//
// The UIViewControllerContextTransitioning protocol can be adopted by custom
// container controllers.  It is purposely general to cover more complex
// transitions than the system currently supports. For now, navigation push/pops
// and UIViewController present/dismiss transitions can be
// customized. Information about the transition is obtained by using the
// viewControllerForKey:, initialFrameForViewController:, and
// finalFrameForViewController: methods. The system provides two keys for
// identifying the from view controller and the to view controller for
// navigation push/pop and view controller present/dismiss transitions.
//
// ...
//

public protocol UIViewControllerContextTransitioning : NSObjectProtocol { ... }
```

So, can we ?

I want to create a custom container view controller which could provide a context to another object if this one wants to manage the transitions when one of the children is inserted or removed. [Just as `UINavigationController` does](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uinavigationcontrollerdelegate/1621846-navigationcontroller).

Comment: why don't you simply subclass from uiviewcontroller?

Comment: @MaksTheAwesome Could you be more specific ? Sure, my container is a ` UIViewController`.